# java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine() returns true even if there is no next line available

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Suppose following code:

```
String example = "  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode\n" +
    "   0: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0\n" +
    "   1: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(example);
scanner.useRadix(16).useDelimiter("[\\s:]+");

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    scanner.nextLine(); // skip header on first iteration, which is not needed
    int slot = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(slot);
}
```

I am basically reading the first integer on each line except the header. I'm expecting to see following output:

```
0
1
```

But exception thrown instead:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

The question is why `Scanner.hasNextLine()` returns `true` on the last line where clearly no newline available in the stream?

---

Comment: It does have a newline *character* that not yet been consumed

Comment: I find its easier to just always use `nextLine` and parse object manually.

Comment: Correct we if I wrong, but example contains exactly 2 newline characters but `hasNextLine()` returns `true` 3 times.

Comment: Just to be safe, you should be checking to see if hasNextInt() returns true prior to using nextInt().

Comment: Yep, thanks. Example has been simplified to be more transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens at the end of your input. You parse the `1`, which leaves you at the space following it. Then your loop condition is still true (there's a line available), so you read the line, which leaves you at the very end of your string. Then, with no checks, you try to read an int. So it fails. You need to check whether there's an int available, because on the last line, there isn't.

Here's a version checking to see if there's an int available, and showing what you're skipping, which should make things clearer ([live copy](http://ideone.com/QdPBYU)):

```
String example = "  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode\n" +
    "   0: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0\n" +
    "   1: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(example);
scanner.useRadix(16).useDelimiter("[\\s:]+");
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
scanner.next();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String skipped = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Skipped: " + skipped); // skip header on first iteration and also skips remainder of previous line after we read the int
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int slot = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(slot);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No int avaialble");
    }
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

There I've added a `System.out.println` for what's skipped, but really what you want to do is step through this in a debugger.

Here's what it ouputs:

```
Skipped:   local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
0
Skipped: : 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0
1
Skipped: : 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0
No int avaialble
Done
```

---

Now, the above is a bit complicated because you're reading part of the line (the int at the beginning) on one loop but reading the rest of the line (the part after the int) at the beginning of the next loop. Ideally you'd clean those up in the same loop ([live copy](http://ideone.com/amMc7G)):

```
String example = "  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode\n" +
    "   0: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0\n" +
    "   1: 00000000:04D2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15662 1 ffff8800baf1c780 100 0 0 10 0";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(example);
scanner.useRadix(16).useDelimiter("[\\s:]+");
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
scanner.next();

if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // Skip the headers
    scanner.nextLine();
}
// Process records
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // The first int
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int slot = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(slot);

        // Read anything else you want from that line, until
        // you have only the newline left (or any trailing characters
        // you don't want to process and then the newline)
    }

    // Clear the newline
    scanner.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

Output:

```
0
1
Done
```

Comment: *(**Doh!** If you see "You parse the 0" above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: It seems to confront with `Scanner.hasNextLine()` documentation. It says: _Returns true if there is *another line* in the input of this scanner._

Comment: @DenisBazhenov: You aren't removing a "line" with `nextInt`, so there's no conflict.

Comment: It doesn't seem that way. Note that I'm using `useDelimeter()`. In fact after `slot` I'm reading a bunch of other tokens on the same line very happily (the example is simplified).

Comment: @DenisBazhenov: Apparently, nothing you're doing is consuing the newline at the end. `hasNextLine` will remain true until you remove that newline.

Comment: But there is no newline at the end of the `example`

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. You were right. It's just midnight on the clock. Silly question, sorry :)